# XSockets.Net Server onOpen event implementation

Tags: c#, xsockets.net

I tweak XSockets.Net Server now.

I read http://xsockets.net/docs/c-server-api#using_events

### Using events

The server side API offer a few events to help you out.

#### OnOpen

Invoked when the client is connected and the handshake is completed.

```
//Hook up the event in the constructor.
public MyController()
{
    this.OnOpen += MyController_OnOpen;
}

void MyController_OnOpen(object sender, OnClientConnectArgs e)
{
    //The connection is open...
}
```

so, if I do the below in VisualStduio.net

```
  class MyController : XSocketController
        {
            //Hook up the event in the constructor.
            public MyController()
            {
                this.OnOpen += MyController_OnOpen;
            }

            void MyController_OnOpen(object sender, OnClientConnectArgs e)
            {
                //The connection is open...
            }

        }
```

`MyController_OnOpen` and `OnClientConnectArgs` is cautioned with red underline, which obviously means no good and not going to work.

I was an OK C# coder before, and now I do node.js.

I know what they try to do is

```
var myController = XSocketCotroller();

var myController_onOpen = function(obj,e)
                        {
                           // The connection is open...
                        };

myControler.onOpen = myController_onOpen;
```

simple enough, but I don't know how to do this in C#.

Could you instruct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that you are using XSockets 3.0.6 ?
But I will write samples for both 3.0.6 and the new 4.0

There is really no idea sending a connected event from the onOpen since the server will send a event automatically...

The name of the controller you have "Server" confuses me, anyway see below.

### Server side

**3.0.6**

```
using XSockets.Core.Common.Socket.Event.Arguments;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket;
using XSockets.Core.XSocket.Helpers;

namespace KenOkabe
{
    public class SampleController : XSocketController
    {
        public SampleController()
        {
            this.OnOpen += SampleController_OnOpen;
        }

        void SampleController_OnOpen(object sender, OnClientConnectArgs e)
        {
            //Send connected topic to client that connected.
            //Just passing a anonymous object with info about the client, but it can be anything serializable..
            this.Send(new {this.ClientGuid, this.StorageGuid},"connected");
        }
    }
}
```

**4.0**

```
public class SampleController : XSocketController
{
    public SampleController()
    {
        this.OnOpen += SampleController_OnOpen;
    }

    void SampleController_OnOpen(object sender, OnClientConnectArgs e)
    {
        //Send connected topic to client that connected.
        //Just passing a anonymous object with info about the client, but it can be anything serializable..
        this.Invoke(new { this.ConnectionId, this.Context.PersistentId }, "connected");
    }
}
```

### Client side

**3.0.6**

```
var client = new XSocketClient("ws://127.0.0.1:4502/SampleController", "*");
client.OnOpen += (sender, eventArgs) => { Console.WriteLine("OPEN"); };
client.Bind("connected", textArgs => Console.WriteLine(textArgs.data));
client.Open();
```

**4.0**

```
var client = new XSocketClient("ws://127.0.0.1:4502", "http://localhost", "SampleController");
client.Controller("SampleController").OnOpen += (sender, connectArgs) => Console.WriteLine("OPEN");
client.Controller("SampleController").On("connected",data => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", data.ConnectionId, data.PersistentId)));
client.Open();
```

So the big difference between 3.* and 4.* is that you can multiplex over several controllers on one socket.

4.0 will support RPC and that makes the binding to "connected" obsolete... We can just call the method directly from the server using "Invoke"

Guessing that you are writing some custom client in NodeJS, but you will still receive the OnOpen data without sending it yourself from the OnOpen event on the controller!

Regards
Uffe

Comment: thanks a lot for this dedicated answer. I probably need to update to 4.0 as you recommended. Having said that, hereby another question. As I mentioned earlier, I plan to use node.js client, not C#. I probably need to launch another dedicated question for the xSockets.net. Regards. will post the link here.

Comment: I post another question. Please check it out if you would like. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586774/xsockets-net-server-4-0-port-and-node-js-ws-client-example thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do

```
  public class Server : XSocketController
    {
        public Server()
        { 
            this.OnOpen += onOpen; 
        }

        void onOpen(object sender, XSockets.Core.Common.Socket.Event.Arguments.OnClientConnectArgs e)
        {
            this.send("connected");
        }
        public void send(String msg)
        {
            this.send(msg);
        }

    }
```

`OnClientConnectArgs e)` is not sufficient that occurs the error.